# EJB jar dependency in the web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a ejbproject, a web project and a application project. 
Now I want to design a decoupled environment where Web is completely independent of ejb project. Web will only have refrence of the ejb stubs nothing else (domain objet etc..)
So far in the current system domain objects are directly getting used in the jsps. I know if I create value objects it will provide a loose coupling.

#### Questions

1. Where should I place my value objects? in ejb or in web? If I put it in ejb then I have to provide reference of the ejb project in the web which contradicts ejb concept (**is it correct?**).
2. My understanding is on each request value objects will get populated. Thru business deligate we will call a ejb operation. then ejb will return a domain object. through domain object we will populate the value objects. But where at ejb or at web?
3. What is the best practice in such situation?

My solution is create a common jar and put the value objects in the common jar. use the common jar in both. Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since I did this kind of stuff so I'm hazy on details, but the basic concept of where to put things should be business logic, and all the database transactioney stuff in the EJBs and the front end (web) should be all logically broken up ejb calls.

I remember using websphere that it did a lot of the create-all-the-goofy-ejb-binding for you and there were limits to what you could pass back and forth. So you want to be passing end user displayable data back from the ejb to the web layer, nothing more complex than that.
You can't pass database connections or heavy objects like that, it just won't work. Keep it simple, the less over the wire the better anyway.